# protractor span repeated cycle

Tags: jasmine, protractor

On the bellow code, how can i get the value "Start test"?

```
<div class="nea-sidebar" _ngcontent-c2="">
<a class="sidebar-item active" href="#/test" _ngcontent-c2="" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="test" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active">
<i class="sidebar-icon fas fa-play" _ngcontent-c2="" ng-reflect-klass="sidebar-icon fas" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa-play"></i>
<span class="sidebar-label" _ngcontent-c2="">Start Test</span></a>

<a class="sidebar-item" href="#/sequences" _ngcontent-c2="" routerlinkactive="active" ng-reflect-router-link="sequences" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active">
<i class="sidebar-icon fas fa-project-diagram" _ngcontent-c2="" ng-reflect-klass="sidebar-icon fas" ng-reflect-ng-class="fa-project-diagram"></i>
<span class="sidebar-label" _ngcontent-c2="">Sequences</span></a>

.
.
.
/>
```

I'm using:
    element(by.className('sidebar-label')).isDisplayed().then(function(isVisible) 
    {
    if (isVisible) {
    // tests -- validar caminho, icon ... label  sidebar-label
    expect(element(by. className('sidebar-label')).getAttribute('_ngcontent-c2')).toBe('Start Test');
    }

But it returns failed due "  - Expected '' to be 'Start Test'.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code, copy the relevant bit of code into your question body.

Comment: I just changed it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
element(by.css('.nea-sidebar '))
.element(by.cssContainingText('.sidebar-label', 'Start Test')).isDisplayed()
   .then(function(isDisplayed) {
     expect(isDisplayed).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

`by.cssContainingText(selector, text)` looks for an element with given `selector` containing a given `text`. If that element is displayed, that means protractor actually found such element containing such text.

Comment: Thank you. I tested it, failed due "No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("sidebar-label", "Start Test")"

Comment: I checked the help for cssContainingText, It was missing a . before side-bar                  It works :D

Comment: Ah yes, little typo. I adjusted the answer. It's also possible to mark an answer as accepted so other users see it was successfully answered.

Comment: How can é mark? 


Do you know how to get the hrf from code example?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to get the `href` attribute from an `<a>` tag ?
If yes you could try the following: `element.all(by.css('.sidebaritem').first().getAttribute('href').then(function(value) { console.log('href value:' , value); });`
I am using `element.all()` here since there exist multiple elements matching to selector `.sidebar-item`.